# why graphich layout not display in android?

Tags: android

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- TextView (Change to android.widget.TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

Hi
could you please tell me why my xml is not display ..I also restart my eclipse and also import project .but still same error come .Actually what I did I just copy and past the xml from there that error come .there is my issue I am not able to see graphic layout.

```
![<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e6e6e6"
    tools:context="com.firstgroup.applicationload.Appliacationload" >

    <!--
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
    </ListView>
    -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
         android:background="@drawable/headerbar"
         android:padding="10dip">
          <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
          android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textViewtest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:text="@string/appsetting"
            android:background="@drawable/pinkbuttonbackground"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp"

            android:textAppearance="@dimen/textfontsize" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>][1]
```

[image]